# rustでmongoのドライバーを使用してますがうまくいきません。

Tags: rust, mongodb

actix-webのexampleをダウンロードしてmongodbの機能を確かめていました。
https://github.com/actix/examples
初めからinsertとfindはありましたが、updateがなかったので自分で実装してテストしてみましたが、うまく動きません。

main関数

```rust
//! Example code for using MongoDB with Actix.
mod model;
#[cfg(test)]
mod test;

use actix_web::{get, post, web, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer};
use model::User;
use mongodb::{bson::doc, options::IndexOptions, Client, Collection, IndexModel};
use mongodb::options::UpdateOptions;

const DB_NAME: &str = "myApp";
const COLL_NAME: &str = "users";

/// Adds a new user to the "users" collection in the database.
#[post("/add_user")]
async fn add_user(client: web::Data<Client>, form: web::Form<User>) -> HttpResponse {
    let collection = client.database(DB_NAME).collection(COLL_NAME);
    let result = collection.insert_one(form.into_inner(), None).await;
    match result {
        Ok(_) => HttpResponse::Ok().body("user added"),
        Err(err) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(err.to_string()),
    }
}

/// Gets the user with the supplied username.
#[get("/get_user/{username}")]
async fn get_user(client: web::Data<Client>, id: web::Path<String>) -> HttpResponse {
    let id: i32 = id.into_inner().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
    let collection: Collection<User> = client.database(DB_NAME).collection(COLL_NAME);
    match collection
        .find_one(doc! { "id": &id }, None)
        .await
    {
        Ok(Some(user)) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(user),
        Ok(None) => {
            HttpResponse::NotFound().body(format!("No user found with username {id}"))
        }
        Err(err) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(err.to_string()),
    }
    
}
/// Change the user with the supplied query and value.
#[post("/update_user/{filter}/{update}")]
async fn update_user(
    client: web::Data<Client>,
    filter: web::Path<String>,
    update: web::Path<String>,
) -> HttpResponse {


    println!("1");
    let filter = doc! { "name": filter.into_inner() };
    println!("2");
    let update: mongodb::bson::Document = doc! { "$set": { "last_name": update.into_inner() } };
    println!("3");

    let collection: Collection<User> = client.database(DB_NAME).collection(COLL_NAME);
    println!("4");
    let update_options = UpdateOptions::default();
    
    let result = collection.update_one(filter, update, update_options).await;
    println!("{:?}",result);

    match result {
        Ok(_) => HttpResponse::Ok().body("User updated"),
        Err(err) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().body(err.to_string()),
    }
}

/// Creates an index on the "username" field to force the values to be unique.
async fn create_username_index(client: &Client) {
    let options = IndexOptions::builder().unique(true).build();
    let model = IndexModel::builder()
        .keys(doc! { "username": 1 })
        .options(options)
        .build();
    client
        .database(DB_NAME)
        .collection::<User>(COLL_NAME)
        .create_index(model, None)
        .await
        .expect("creating an index should succeed");
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let uri = std::env::var("MONGODB_URI").unwrap_or_else(|_| "mongodb://localhost:27017".into());

    let client = Client::with_uri_str(uri).await.expect("failed to connect");
    create_username_index(&client).await;

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(client.clone()))
            .service(add_user)
            .service(get_user)
            .service(update_user)
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

テスト関数

```rust
use actix_web::{
    test::{call_and_read_body, call_and_read_body_json, init_service, TestRequest},
    web::Bytes,
};
use mongodb::Client;
//use rand::Rng;
use chrono::Utc;
use mongodb::options::UpdateModifications;
use mongodb::bson::Document;


use crate::model::QueryForUpdateValue;

use super::*;

#[actix_web::test]
//#[ignore = "requires MongoDB instance running"]
async fn test() {
    let uri = std::env::var("MONGODB_URI").unwrap_or_else(|_| "mongodb://localhost:27017".into());

    let client = Client::with_uri_str(uri).await.expect("failed to connect");

    // Clear any data currently in the users collection.
    client
        .database(DB_NAME)
        .collection::<User>(COLL_NAME)
        .drop(None)
        .await
        .expect("drop collection should succeed");

    let app = init_service(
        App::new()
            .app_data(web::Data::new(client))
            .service(add_user)
            .service(get_user),
    )
    .await;
    
    for i in 0..1{
        let text = Utc::now().format("%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分%S秒 %f").to_string();
        let user = User {
            id:i,
            first_name: "Jane".into(),
            last_name: "Doe".into(),
            username: "janedoe".into(),
            email: "example@example.com".into(),
            time:text.into()
        };

        let req = TestRequest::post()
            .uri("/add_user")
            .set_form(&user)
            .to_request();

        let response = call_and_read_body(&app, req).await;
        assert_eq!(response, Bytes::from_static(b"user added"));
    }
    
    for i in 0..1{

    
        let req = TestRequest::get()
            .uri(&format!("/get_user/{}", i))
            .to_request();

        let response: User = call_and_read_body_json(&app, req).await;
        println!("{:?}{:?}",response,Utc::now().format("%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分%S秒 %f").to_string());
        //assert_eq!(response, user);
    }
    
    let name="Jane".to_string();
    let LastName="ddd".to_string();

    let req=TestRequest::post()
        .uri(&format!("/update_user/{}/{}",name,LastName))
        .to_request();
    let responce:String=call_and_read_body_json(&app,req).await;
}
```

エラーメッセージ

```
running 1 test
User { id: 0, first_name: "Jane", last_name: "Doe", username: "janedoe", email: "example@example.com", time: "2023年10月13日 15時59分14秒 795429800" }"2023年10月13日 15時59分14秒 855553600"
thread 'test::test' panicked at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\actix-web-4.4.0\src\test\test_utils.rs:328:49:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0)
stack backtrace:
   0: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler
             at /rustc/5ae769f06bbe2afc50cde219757a5915e61ba365/library\std\src\panicking.rs:597
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/5ae769f06bbe2afc50cde219757a5915e61ba365/library\core\src\panicking.rs:72
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/5ae769f06bbe2afc50cde219757a5915e61ba365/library\core\src\result.rs:1652
   3: enum2$<core::result::Result<alloc::string::String,alloc::boxed::Box<dyn$<core::error::Error>,alloc::alloc::Global> > >::unwrap<alloc::string::String,alloc::boxed::Box<dyn$<core::error::Error>,alloc::alloc::Global> >
             at /rustc/5ae769f06bbe2afc50cde219757a5915e61ba365\library\core\src\result.rs:1077
   4: actix_web::test::test_utils::call_and_read_body_json::async_fn$0<actix_web::app_service::AppInitService<actix_web::app_service::AppRouting,actix_http::body::boxed::BoxBody>,actix_http::body::boxed::BoxBody,alloc::string::String>
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\actix-web-4.4.0\src\test\test_utils.rs:328
   5: mongodb::test::test::async_block$0
             at .\src\test.rs:77
   6: tokio::task::local::impl$8::poll::closure$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\task\local.rs:949
   7: tokio::task::local::impl$2::with::closure$0<enum2$<core::task::poll::Poll<tuple$<> > >,tokio::task::local::impl$8::poll::closure_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> > >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\task\local.rs:686
   8: std::thread::local::LocalKey<tokio::task::local::LocalData>::try_with<tokio::task::local::LocalData,tokio::task::local::impl$2::with::closure_env$0<enum2$<core::task::poll::Poll<tuple$<> > >,tokio::task::local::impl$8::poll::closure_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::
             at /rustc/5ae769f06bbe2afc50cde219757a5915e61ba365\library\std\src\thread\local.rs:270
   9: std::thread::local::LocalKey<tokio::task::local::LocalData>::with<tokio::task::local::LocalData,tokio::task::local::impl$2::with::closure_env$0<enum2$<core::task::poll::Poll<tuple$<> > >,tokio::task::local::impl$8::poll::closure_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test
             at /rustc/5ae769f06bbe2afc50cde219757a5915e61ba365\library\std\src\thread\local.rs:246
  10: tokio::task::local::LocalSet::with<enum2$<core::task::poll::Poll<tuple$<> > >,tokio::task::local::impl$8::poll::closure_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> > >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\task\local.rs:669
  11: tokio::task::local::impl$8::poll<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\task\local.rs:939
  12: tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\task\local.rs:575
  13: core::future::future::impl$1::poll<ref_mut$<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> > > > >
             at /rustc/5ae769f06bbe2afc50cde219757a5915e61ba365\library\core\src\future\future.rs:125
  14: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$8::block_on::closure$0::closure$0::closure$0<core::pin::Pin<ref_mut$<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> > > > > >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\scheduler\current_thread\mod.rs:665  
  15: tokio::runtime::coop::with_budget
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\coop.rs:107
  16: tokio::runtime::coop::budget
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\coop.rs:73
  17: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$8::block_on::closure$0::closure$0<core::pin::Pin<ref_mut$<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> > > > > >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\scheduler\current_thread\mod.rs:665  
  18: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::Context::enter<enum2$<core::task::poll::Poll<tuple$<> > >,tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$8::block_on::closure$0::closure_env$0<core::pin::Pin<ref_mut$<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\scheduler\current_thread\mod.rs:410  
  19: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$8::block_on::closure$0<core::pin::Pin<ref_mut$<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> > > > > >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\scheduler\current_thread\mod.rs:664  
  20: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$8::enter::closure$0<tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$8::block_on::closure_env$0<core::pin::Pin<ref_mut$<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test:
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\scheduler\current_thread\mod.rs:743  
  21: tokio::runtime::context::scoped::Scoped<enum2$<tokio::runtime::scheduler::Context> >::set<enum2$<tokio::runtime::scheduler::Context>,tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$8::enter::closure_env$0<tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$8:
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\context\scoped.rs:40
  22: tokio::runtime::context::set_scheduler::closure$0<tuple$<alloc::boxed::Box<tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::Core,alloc::alloc::Global>,enum2$<core::option::Option<tuple$<> > > >,tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$8::enter::closure_e
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\context.rs:176
  23: std::thread::local::LocalKey<tokio::runtime::context::Context>::try_with<tokio::runtime::context::Context,tokio::runtime::context::set_scheduler::closure_env$0<tuple$<alloc::boxed::Box<tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::Core,alloc::alloc::Global>,
             at /rustc/5ae769f06bbe2afc50cde219757a5915e61ba365\library\std\src\thread\local.rs:270
  24: std::thread::local::LocalKey<tokio::runtime::context::Context>::with<tokio::runtime::context::Context,tokio::runtime::context::set_scheduler::closure_env$0<tuple$<alloc::boxed::Box<tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::Core,alloc::alloc::Global>,enum
             at /rustc/5ae769f06bbe2afc50cde219757a5915e61ba365\library\std\src\thread\local.rs:246
  25: tokio::runtime::context::set_scheduler<tuple$<alloc::boxed::Box<tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::Core,alloc::alloc::Global>,enum2$<core::option::Option<tuple$<> > > >,tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$8::enter::closure_env$0<tokio:
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\context.rs:176
  26: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CoreGuard::enter<tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$8::block_on::closure_env$0<core::pin::Pin<ref_mut$<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_b
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\scheduler\current_thread\mod.rs:743  
  27: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CoreGuard::block_on<core::pin::Pin<ref_mut$<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> > > > > >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\scheduler\current_thread\mod.rs:652  
  28: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$0::block_on::closure$0<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> > > >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\scheduler\current_thread\mod.rs:175  
  29: tokio::runtime::context::runtime::enter_runtime<tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::impl$0::block_on::closure_env$0<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> > > >,tuple$<> >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\context\runtime.rs:65
  30: tokio::runtime::scheduler::current_thread::CurrentThread::block_on<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> > > >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\scheduler\current_thread\mod.rs:167  
  31: tokio::runtime::runtime::Runtime::block_on<enum2$<tokio::task::local::impl$2::run_until::async_fn_env$0<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> > > >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\runtime\runtime.rs:347
  32: tokio::task::local::LocalSet::block_on<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.32.0\src\task\local.rs:536
  33: actix_rt::runtime::Runtime::block_on<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\actix-rt-2.9.0\src\runtime.rs:138
  34: actix_rt::system::SystemRunner::block_on<enum2$<mongodb::test::test::async_block_env$0> >
             at C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\actix-rt-2.9.0\src\system.rs:245
  35: mongodb::test::test
             at .\src\test.rs:16
  36: mongodb::test::test::closure$0
             at .\src\test.rs:16
  37: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once<mongodb::test::test::closure_env$0,tuple$<> >
             at /rustc/5ae769f06bbe2afc50cde219757a5915e61ba365\library\core\src\ops\function.rs:250
  38: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/5ae769f06bbe2afc50cde219757a5915e61ba365/library\core\src\ops\function.rs:250
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
test test::test ... FAILED

failures:

failures:
    test::test

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 41.96s

error: test failed, to rerun pass `-p mongodb --bin mongodb`

 *  The terminal process "C:\Users\shinj\.cargo\bin\cargo.exe 'test', '--package', 'mongodb:1.0.0', '--bin', 'mongodb', '--', 'test::test', '--exact', '--nocapture'" terminated with exit code: 101. 
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```